# Opening sockets between 2 Android phones

Tags: android, sockets

Is it possible to open a socket between 2 Android phones?  How can this be done so the devices can communicate between each other?

Comment: I do believe I've seen some apps out there connecting adhoc with wifi

Answer (score 5):

[Using Socket Programming with Android](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/03/27/incorporating-socket-programming-into-your-applications/) is a very good read on the topic, it explains how to do Socket Programming with Android and also lists some useful example.

Also, this [discussion](http://www.anddev.org/socket_programming-t325-s30.html) lists some very useful pointers for Socket Programming on Android Platform

Comment: You could use UDP to have the phones auto discover each other as well.